# Contemporary painters.

Tags: word-usage

The word contemporary can mean two mutually exclusive things.

```
 1.living or occurring at the same time.
 2.belonging to or occurring in the present.
```

As a result, if I read the sentence

```
Bob and contemporary painters...
```

I could interpret it as "Bob, and painters living in the present" or as "Bob, and painters living in the same time".

How can I phrase the sentence so that possible confusion is avoided while still making use of the word "contemporary"?

Comment: Well, which definition are you trying to convey: the first or the second?

Comment: Saying "...and his contemporaries" works if you're discussing painters of the same era. It gives no information about which era, but presumably "Bob" does give you that info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the first case obvious by making 'contemporary' refer to Bob specifically.  For the painters living at the same time as Bob:

> Bob and **his** contemporaries...

I would use a different phrasing, since I think the first sense of the word is stronger and most people would assume it.  So for the case of Bob living in the past, and other painters living today:

> Bob and present-day painters...

If you're dead set on using 'contemporary', you have to do something to indicate that there is a time difference.

> Bob, during 19xx-19yy, as well as contemporary painters, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to convey the first definition, you could reword your sentence as follows: “Bob and [contemporaneous](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/contemporaneous) painters...” (You could also use synonyms of “contemporaneous,” except, of course, “contemporary.”)

If you are trying to convey the second definition, you could reword your sentence like this: “Bob and [latter-day](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/latter-day) painters...” If you don’t like “latter-day,” you could also use [“present-day.”](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/present-day)

Answer (score 0):

The only thing you need to do is specify the time you are referring to, as such:

- Bob and his contemporary painters nowadays work their magic using advanced color-replacement algorithms...
- Bob and his contemporaries at the beginning of the 20th century at first weren't sure what to make of Picasso, though later they enthusiastically adopted his practices, almost to the point of aping him.